# Input Stream returns null for mentioned file path

Tags: java, jasper-reports, inputstream

[image]

I am trying to access the sample_report.jrxml file from ReportUtil.java .

Following is the code to access the jrxml file :

```
InputStream in = new ReportUtil().getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource/sample_report.jrxml");
```

I am getting in as NULL. I tried various combinations to read the jrxml file.

Can any one point correct way to get the file ?

Comment: `resources != resource`

Comment: ^^ To be explicit: You have a typo. Your directory name is *plural*. You *also* have a `resource` directory. What's really important is what is being included in the resulting `.jar` and where.

Answer (score 0):

Make an entry of resources folder in your classpath.

Comment: it's ... a simple typo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your project is a maven project and you follow maven conventions, then
your file **sample_report.jrxml** residing in **resources** folder will be copied into the root level of the generated jar file.

For loading files you should use:

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "sample_report.jrxml" );
```

[BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) has explained this very well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2308388)

And as **Brian Roach** pointed out, there is a typo in the path to your file.